# Lack of Log Entry for Unhandled Error in Server Side SuiteScript 2.x

Tags: error-handling, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I suppose that this is more of a curiosity as opposed to an actual issue, but I thought I'd ask about it anyway. There are times when an uncaught error occurs in a server-side NetSuite script using SuiteScript 2.0/2.1 (2.x), but instead of seeing a "SYSTEM" scripting log entry, there's nothing. It gives the appearance of a script just stopping for no reason. Now, I know this can easily be avoided by wrapping everything within a try-catch block, but that's not what I'm trying to discuss here.

Does anyone have any insight into why a script would just stop without any SYSTEM error logging? It's just something I find interesting given that with the 1.0 API uncaught errors would always get logged. And it's not a guarantee that an uncaught error won't be logged as a SYSTEM log. It seems more common with map/reduce scripts, but unless memory is not serving correctly I believe that I have seen it happen with suitelets and user event scripts, too.

Just thought that I'd pose the question here to see if there was anyone who might know a little something about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually covered in the system help for Map/Reduce scripts. They do fail silently. I've not seen this in any other script type.

Comment: Must have been one of those things that NetSuite added to the documentation some time after I initially read it. Keep finding new stuff in there from time to time. But I have had some odd silent failures in user events. The script seems to terminate without cause. I guess it's just another one of the NetSuite dev's brilliant ideas.